# Problems with Echo Nest Earworm analyzing small mp3s

Tags: python

Alright everyone, this one is super niche:

I am attempting to use the earworm.py code to analyze the timbre and pitch features of very short mp3s/tracks (1 second minimum); however, the code is returning no features and an empty graph.

The issue seems to stem from the function get_central(analysis, member='segments'). With short tracks, '"member = getattr(analysis, member)" returns empty.

Why is this? Is there a quick fix I could use like changing "member='segments'" to something that is more fine-grained?

Is there a way to extract timbre and pitch features from such short tracks using EchoNest?

Comment: Correction: when member in get_central is 'segments', it returns features; but not when member='beats'. What is the difference between these?

Comment: TEMP FIX: changed global "rate" variable in earworm.py from 'beats' to 'segments' and it successfully produces a graph for tracks of a minimum of 1 second. Does someone know if this will have any negative effects on analysis?